# I am looking for something like an if query in java

Tags: excel, if-statement

Hello I have to work on an excel file and I want to do my work easier.
I have to insert a shortcut to an associated number.
For Example:  If in row b is a "1" , i have to insert "ABC" in row E , if in row "b" is a 3, I have to insert "GHI" .

So i need something like an if- query in Excel.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a simple formula:

```
=IF(B1=1,"ABC",IF(B1=2,"DEF","GHI"))
```